# Delete SQL Membership from Website

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, iis-6, sqlmembershipprovider

My company had a website where we manage our timesheets which is developed in ASP.NET 2.0. Recently we made a decision to use LDAP Authentication instead of using the SQL Membership that we used previously.
Now this is generating all sorts of problems since the membership data is spread along some of the most important tables with GUIDs FKs on some tables that rely on aspnet_Users.

In terms of authentication we don't have any problems but we want to drop every table and column that references anything related to the SQL Membership.
I haven't been able to do this so far since I need to drop the asp_* tables first.

I've tried aspnet_regsql.exe (it fails), I've tried the Web Administration tool (I was able to delete some data but not everything) and I still need to delete all these Membership related data.

Can anyone point out how can I achieve the intended outcome? I'm really lost here..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now, if you have data in say an "orders" table that references a user that placed the order (and have a relationship between your membership user table and the orders table) this massive drop statement will fail - how are you accounting for updating your current data attributed to users to your new user store?

Found this copied from https://gist.github.com/dmorrison/942148

```
-- Removes all objects (in the correct order) added to 
-- SQL Server by the stock ASP.NET membership provider
drop table aspnet_PersonalizationAllUsers
drop table aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser
drop table aspnet_Profile
drop table aspnet_SchemaVersions
drop table aspnet_UsersInRoles
drop table aspnet_WebEvent_Events
drop table aspnet_Paths
drop table aspnet_Membership
drop table aspnet_Roles
drop table aspnet_Users
drop table aspnet_Applications

drop view vw_aspnet_Applications
drop view vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers
drop view vw_aspnet_Profiles
drop view vw_aspnet_Roles
drop view vw_aspnet_Users
drop view vw_aspnet_UsersInRoles
drop view vw_aspnet_WebPartState_Paths
drop view vw_aspnet_WebPartState_Shared
drop view vw_aspnet_WebPartState_User

drop procedure aspnet_AnyDataInTables
drop procedure aspnet_Applications_CreateApplication
drop procedure aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion
drop procedure aspnet_Membership_ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer
drop procedure aspnet_Membership_CreateUser
drop procedure aspnet_Membership_FindUsersByEmail
drop procedure aspnet_Membership_FindUsersByName
drop procedure aspnet_Membership_GetAllUsers
drop procedure aspnet_Membership_GetNumberOfUsersOnline
drop procedure aspnet_Membership_GetPassword
drop procedure aspnet_Membership_GetPasswordWithFormat
drop procedure aspnet_Membership_GetUserByEmail
drop procedure aspnet_Membership_GetUserByName
drop procedure aspnet_Membership_GetUserByUserId
drop procedure aspnet_Membership_ResetPassword
drop procedure aspnet_Membership_SetPassword
drop procedure aspnet_Membership_UnlockUser
drop procedure aspnet_Membership_UpdateUser
drop procedure aspnet_Membership_UpdateUserInfo
drop procedure aspnet_Paths_CreatePath
drop procedure aspnet_Personalization_GetApplicationId
drop procedure aspnet_PersonalizationAdministration_DeleteAllState
drop procedure aspnet_PersonalizationAdministration_FindState
drop procedure aspnet_PersonalizationAdministration_GetCountOfState
drop procedure aspnet_PersonalizationAdministration_ResetSharedState
drop procedure aspnet_PersonalizationAdministration_ResetUserState
drop procedure aspnet_PersonalizationAllUsers_GetPageSettings
drop procedure aspnet_PersonalizationAllUsers_ResetPageSettings
drop procedure aspnet_PersonalizationAllUsers_SetPageSettings
drop procedure aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser_GetPageSettings
drop procedure aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser_ResetPageSettings
drop procedure aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser_SetPageSettings
drop procedure aspnet_Profile_DeleteInactiveProfiles
drop procedure aspnet_Profile_DeleteProfiles
drop procedure aspnet_Profile_GetNumberOfInactiveProfiles
drop procedure aspnet_Profile_GetProfiles
drop procedure aspnet_Profile_GetProperties
drop procedure aspnet_Profile_SetProperties
drop procedure aspnet_RegisterSchemaVersion
drop procedure aspnet_Roles_CreateRole
drop procedure aspnet_Roles_DeleteRole
drop procedure aspnet_Roles_GetAllRoles
drop procedure aspnet_Roles_RoleExists
drop procedure aspnet_Setup_RemoveAllRoleMembers
drop procedure aspnet_Setup_RestorePermissions
drop procedure aspnet_UnRegisterSchemaVersion
drop procedure aspnet_Users_CreateUser
drop procedure aspnet_Users_DeleteUser
drop procedure aspnet_UsersInRoles_AddUsersToRoles
drop procedure aspnet_UsersInRoles_FindUsersInRole
drop procedure aspnet_UsersInRoles_GetRolesForUser
drop procedure aspnet_UsersInRoles_GetUsersInRoles
drop procedure aspnet_UsersInRoles_IsUserInRole
drop procedure aspnet_UsersInRoles_RemoveUsersFromRoles
drop procedure aspnet_WebEvent_LogEvent

drop schema aspnet_Membership_FullAccess
drop schema aspnet_Membership_BasicAccess
drop schema aspnet_Membership_ReportingAccess
drop schema aspnet_Personalization_BasicAccess
drop schema aspnet_Personalization_FullAccess
drop schema aspnet_Personalization_ReportingAccess
drop schema aspnet_Profile_BasicAccess
drop schema aspnet_Profile_FullAccess
drop schema aspnet_Profile_ReportingAccess
drop schema aspnet_Roles_BasicAccess
drop schema aspnet_Roles_FullAccess
drop schema aspnet_Roles_ReportingAccess
drop schema aspnet_WebEvent_FullAccess

drop role aspnet_Membership_FullAccess
drop role aspnet_Membership_BasicAccess
drop role aspnet_Membership_ReportingAccess
drop role aspnet_Personalization_FullAccess
drop role aspnet_Personalization_BasicAccess
drop role aspnet_Personalization_ReportingAccess
drop role aspnet_Profile_FullAccess
drop role aspnet_Profile_BasicAccess
drop role aspnet_Profile_ReportingAccess
drop role aspnet_Roles_FullAccess
drop role aspnet_Roles_BasicAccess
drop role aspnet_Roles_ReportingAccess
drop role aspnet_WebEvent_FullAccess
```

Comment: I know I come late.. That wasn't the full resolution to my problem, but it definitely was a big push towards it..